# Writing an SQL Query with a count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

1. Category:

   cat_id, cat_name
2. Topics:

   topic_id, cat_id, topic_name

I want to get list of all cat_names along with a count of topics in topics table against the particular cat_id like

```
Category       Topics
----------------------
ABC            2
CDE            5
```

Would really appreciate a fast help

Thanks

Comment: SELECT category.cat_id as id, category.cat_name as category, count(select * from topics where topics.topic_id=id) as topics from category inner join topics on category.cat_id=topics.cat_id

Comment: You should edit your question it's much better than to write code in comments, it's more readable...

Comment: Aleksandar Miladinovic -- still learning :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` Clause

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Topics', cat_id AS 'Category' FROM Category JOIN Topics ON Category.cat_id = Topics.cat_id
GROUP BY cat_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this query

```
select a.cat_name as category, count(*) as Topics
from category a
  join Topics b on a.cat_id=b.cat_id
group by a.cat_name
```

Comment: This only works for categories having at least one topic, though.

Comment: Left join does the job

Answer (score 0):

```
select cat_name as category,count(topic_id) as topics
from Category
  join Topics on Category.cat_id=Topics.cat_id
group by Category.cat_name;
```

Comment: Wrong GROUP BY clause. It should be one result row per cat_name, not per topic_id.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thanks for your correction ... i didn't noticed it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select cat_name, count(*) as counting
from Category as cat 
  inner join Topics as t on cat.cat_id=t.cat_id
group by cat_name
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
SELECT Category.cat_name as Category,
       (SELECT COUNT(topic_id) FROM  Topics
        WHERE Topics.cat_id = category.cat_id) AS Topics 
FROM Category
```

Comment: Better! Now remove Topics from the main query's from list.

Answer (score 0):

This is your own query that you are showing in your comments:

```
select 
  category.cat_id as id, 
  category.cat_name as category, 
  count(select * from topics where topics.topic_id=id) as topics
from category 
inner join topics on category.cat_id=topics.cat_id;
```

First of all there is a syntax error. Instead of

```
count(select * from topics where topics.topic_id=id) as topics
```

this would have to be

```
(select count(*) from topics where topics.topic_id=id) as topics
```

Then you are reading the topics table twice, once in the join, once in the subquery. So this looks like two tries mixed in one statement. Here are the two options separated:

```
select 
  category.cat_id as id, 
  category.cat_name as category, 
  (select count(*) from topics where topics.topic_id = category.id) as topics
from category;
```

Or:

```
select 
  category.cat_id as id, 
  category.cat_name as category, 
  count(topics.topic_id) as topics
from category 
left join topics on category.cat_id = topics.cat_id
group by category.cat_id;
```